# How to compare int & float in Build ANT

Tags: ant, groovy

I want to compare two float or Integer values in ANT Target.

I try ant-contrib but it did not succeed.

**Any one have an idea?**

Comment: The question is unclear. Show some code and what You've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<script>` command you can execute arbirary java/javascript code and do not supported code. 
For your case, perhaps some similar to :

```
<scriptdef name="compare" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="first" />
    <attribute name="seccond" />
    <![CDATA[
       var first = attributes.get("first");
       var second = attributes.get("second");
       var result = parseFloat(first) > parseFloat(second);
       println ("first > second = " + result);
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

An later use it:

```
<compare first="7.5" second="7.4" />
```